# Access cookie values using VBA Code

Tags: vba

```
MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
getCookie = HTMLDoc.cookie
```

How to access cookies from IE using VBA ? I checked the variable getCookie in debug mode which is returning some random values not key value pair of cookies.

Can anyone put some light on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually its quite easy found after searching for 2 hours.

```
aryCookie = Split(HTMLDoc.cookie, ";")
token = aryCookie(16)
```

This token is nothing but string of key+value.